# How to determine missing font on MacOS/Firefox

Tags: firefox, ventura

I'm having trouble reading some webpages on Firefox and MacOS. I commonly come across sites that look like the following.

Is it possible to determine which font is missing by inspecting the web page source or via web developer tools? The issue seems to be specifically related to Firefox as the fonts are loaded correctly with Chrome and Safari

Edit: Here's an [example](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/5-things-founders-recruiters-should-know-cto-role-neerventure-com/?trk=public_post_feed-article-content)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [apple.se]! Do you have an example to link to?

Comment: @Glorfindel I updated the post with a link

Comment: That doesn't look like a font issue as such. Font substitution would replace it with the same words set out differently. That looks like intentional obfuscation, possibly as a result of malware. if you copy/paste the text either into your question or to TextEdit etc, you would see whether that carries through or reverts to normal.

Comment: you're right @Tetsujin, copying the text to TextEdit seems to show the underlying text correctly.

What could the issue be then?

Comment: I honestly don't know for sure. If it had been an Asian site, i could blame incorrect 1-byte/2-byte conversions… but it's LInkedIn. It's not really a site likely to get simple things wrong.That really only leaves me with malware, some 'plugin/extension' or something you may not necessarily have invited in intentionally. That it affects only one browser reinforces that slightly, but not totally convincingly. Maybe run Malwarebytes, see if it finds anything.

Comment: In Firefox, what do you have as the default font and language settings?

Answer (score 1):

Someone answered my problem on SO, that you could use the `inspector` tab of the Firefox web tools to determine the font family of a particular snippet of text. I was able to determine that I was missing a Google font, specifically `Source serif Pro`. I've installed the font and the problem disappeared.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75043441/5536001

Comment: I don't have Source Serif Pro either, yet I can see it perfectly well in any browser. Font substitution on web sites doesn't generally require you have a specific font, merely a generic one in a similar font family. Mac & Windows users tend to see different fonts on most sites they ever visit.